# Perl loop stuck reading file?

Tags: perl, split, readline, while-loop

**Closing this question. Will drink red bull. Sleep. Code and come back with brand spanking new question with unit test cases.**

UPDATE: The new file is [here](http://wtfperl.pastebin.com/m50b16ec6)

Also the config file is [here](http://wtfperl.pastebin.com/m2fca2cd6)

I refactored the code again:

```
sub getColumns {
    open my $input, '<', $ETLSplitter::configFile
        or die "Error opening '$ETLSpliter::configFile': $!";

    my $cols;
    while( my $conline = <$input> ) {
        chomp $conline;
        my @values = split (/=>/, $conline);
        if ($ETLSplitter::name =~ $values[0] ) {
            $cols = $values[1];
            last;
        }
    }

    if($cols) {
        @ETLSplitter::columns = split (':', $cols);
    }
    else {
        die("$ETLSplitter::name is not specified in the config file");
    }
}
```

This code always dies here `die("$ETLSplitter::name is not specified in the config file");`.

Another clue is that if I change `split (':', $cols);` to `split (/:/, $cols);` I get this error.

```
 perl -wle "
 use modules::ETLSplitter;
 \$test = ETLSplitter->new('cpr_operator_metric_actual_d2', 'frame/');
 \$test->prepareCSV();"
 syntax error at modules/ETLSplitter.pm line 154, near "}continue"
 Compilation failed in require at -e line 2.
 BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 2.
```

Comment: Does this still happen if you remove the unnecessary "`next;`" at the end?

Comment: it seems to break as soon as I put in a / character used in my split()

Comment: Ya it still does. Even without the next!

Comment: The first argument to split is a regular expression. If you use "/" as the delimiter you'll need to escape any literal occurrences of it in the pattern. Alternately, you can use an alternative delimiter like "m!pattern!"

Comment: Would you mind telling us how you determinded that your code is "stuck"?

Comment: @Manni Presumably because `getColumns` was not returning anything useful -- Of course, that is due to the fact that he was not putting anything useful in `@columns`.

Comment: Are you now saying that your code is no longer stuck , but you get a syntax error?

Comment: And are you really saying that you do all this from the command line? You copy the complete source code and then paste it after "perl -wle"?

Comment: nope same problem. +clue (syntax error) I call it. The puzzle is the code is stuck whenever I use '/' character in that subroutine.

Comment: How are you running the code? Those last 7 lines in your post are really confusing.

Comment: $  perl -wle "
 use modules::ETLSplitter;
 \$test = ETLSplitter->new('cpr_operator_metric_actual_d2', 'frame/');
 \$test->prepareCSV();"

Comment: Are you really trying to write a complete Perl program on the command line every time you invoke this? Just put the script in a file and invoke it. Look up `@ARGV`. In the mean time, voting to close this as no longer relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FINAL POST FOR THIS QUESTION:** Based on your latest updates, I believe the following code illustrates how there is no problem with using `/:/` as the first argument to `split`. It also points out that it is easier to read code when one uses arguments to functions rather than relying on global variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

for my $varname ( qw( adntopr.cpr.smtref.actv cpr_operator_detail )) {
    print $varname, "\n";
    print Dumper get_columns(\*DATA, $varname);
}

sub get_columns {
    my ($input_fh, $varname) = @_;

    while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        my @values = split /=>/, $line;
        next unless $varname eq $values[0];
        return [ split /:/, $values[1] ];
    }
    return;
}

__DATA__
adntopr.cpr.smtref.actv=>3:8:18:29:34:38:46:51:53:149
adntopr.smtsale2=>3:8:16:22:27:37:39:47:52:57:62:82:102:120:138:234:239:244:249:250:259:262:277:282:287:289:304:319:327:331:335:339:340:341:342:353:364:375:386:397:408
cpr_operator_detail=>3:11:18:28:124:220:228:324
cpr_operator_org_unit_map=>7:12
cpr_operator_metric_actual=>8:15:25:33:38:40:51

C:\Temp> tjm
adntopr.cpr.smtref.actv
$VAR1 = [
          '3',
          '8',
          '18',
          '29',
          '34',
          '38',
          '46',
          '51',
          '53',
          '149'
        ];
cpr_operator_detail
$VAR1 = [
          '3',
          '11',
          '18',
          '28',
          '124',
          '220',
          '228',
          '324'
        ];
```

There is a lot of cruft in that code. Here is my interpretation of what you are trying to do:

**UPDATE:** Given your recent remark about regex special characters in patterns, if you are going to use them in the pattern to split, make sure to quote them. There is also a chance that `$ETLSpliter::name` might contain other special characters. I modified the code to deal with that possibility.

```
sub getColumns {
    open my $input, '<', $ETLSpliter::configFile
          or die "Error opening '$ETLSpliter::configFile': $!");
      my @columns;
      while( my $conline = <$input> ) {
          my @values = split /=>/, $conline;
          print "not at: ".$conline;
          push @columns, $values[1] if $values[0] =~ /\Q$ETLSpliter::name/;
      }
      return @columns;
  }
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

So, the pattern indeed is `/=>/` based on your comment below. Then:

```
my $conline = q{cpr_operator_detail=>3:11:18:28:124:220:228:324};
my @values = split /=>/, $conline;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@values;
__END__

C:\Temp> tml
$VAR1 = [
          'cpr_operator_detail',
          '3:11:18:28:124:220:228:324'
        ];
```

***No errors* ... *No warnings*** Therefore, there is something else that is going on which you insist on not showing us.

**Other Remarks:**

1. Use lexical filehandles and let perl tell you what errors it may encounter rather than presuming.
2. Declare variables in the smallest applicable scope.
3. No need to assign `$_` to `$conline` in the body of the loop when you can do that in the `while` statement.
4. In the original code, you were not putting anything in `@columns` or doing anything useful with `$colData`.
5. Tone down the rhetoric. Computers work on the principle of GIGO.
6. Looking at the code at [the link you posted](http://wtfperl.pastebin.com/m418137f9), it looks like you are not aware that you can do:

   ```
   use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );
   ...
   catfile($ETLSpliter::filepath_results, $ETLSpliter::actual_name);
   ```

Further, it looks like you are using a package where hash would have done the job:

```
$ETLSpliter{filepath}
```

Finally, you do realize `Spliter` is incorrect. ITYM: `Splitter`.

Comment: even then as soon as I use the / character in the loop it breaks? Why is that? I am using perl on cygwin and the file is in [dos] mode in vim? will that make a difference?

Comment: Because you decided to use `/` as the pattern delimiter. No, platform and editor do not make any difference.

Comment: Umm ... still failing due to split(/pattern/, $foo) usage. I have to use split('pattern', $foo). Don't get why this is happening. I am going to implement the changes you said and let me re post the file.

Comment: What is in the pattern? If the pattern contains what you posted, I don't see the problem. If the pattern contains something other than what you posted, well, why did you that? And why don't you go ahead and post what really is in the pattern?

Comment: oops srry. split(/=>/, $conline). $conline looks like this cpr_operator_detail=>3:11:18:28:124:220:228:324

Comment: ok ... Can you stop accusing me of not showing enough information. I have posted the whole file, explained my platform. .... What else do you need? I am at a loss of what the hell is going on too...

Comment: Your code says `split /=>/`. In a comment to your question, you mention putting a `/` somewhere in there. There is no error with `split /=>/`. You are getting errors. Therefore, it is reasonable to assume that what you are running and what you posted are not one and the same.

Comment: Dude I understand that your code is super great awesome. I am still trying to find out why the hell is this not working in my code.

Comment: I just noticed that you seem to be trying to write complete Perl programs on the command line. Maybe that has something to do with it. The downvote is completely unjustified. You can compare what you are doing with what I am doing and figure out where you are putting the G in GI so the computer is giving you GO. In the mean time, this question has become too convoluted.

Comment: Ok I agree. Closing this post. Will drink red bull. Sleep. Code and come back with brand spanking new question with unit test cases.

Comment: If anything, please avoid Red Bull for a while.

Comment: Don't worry about it. If enough people vote to close it, it will be closed. Thank you for accepting my answer. I hope it will be useful.

Comment: you could simply delete the question. There ought to be a link to do that somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that it's stuck? You never store any data in `@columns`, so your code will always return an empty list.

Other notes:

- Your `die` call should include `$!` (OS error). There are other reasons that the `open` could fail besides a non-existent file, and `$!` will tell you what the real problem was.
- You should probably do a `chomp $conline` to get rid of the newline.
- You can do `while (my $conline = <CFILE>)` instead of copying the value from `$_`.
- Two-argument `open` (particularly with an implicit `<` mode) is poor form. Using the three-argument form (ideally with a lexical filehandle) is preferred: `open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die...`

Answer (score 1):

What's in `$ETLSpliter::name` - any `/` chars there should be escaped.

Many other issues in the snippet have already been addressed so I won't go there.

Comment: Why should slashed be escaped in that string?

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT!!!!! Wow Sleep is awesome power.

Anyway. The problem was in $ETLSplitter::configFile in my die message.

```
die ('Error opening '.$ETLSpliter::configFile.': '.$!);
```

Which has winblows path separators '/'. So because I was outputting in double quotation, perl interperted the '/' in the path as patterns. From here

```
die "Error opening some/path/to/ ...
```

to

```
...  /=>/,
```

Which messed with the entire program flow in the subroutine. This was solved by doing this.

```
die ('Error opening '.$ETLSpliter::configFile.': '.$!);
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between the first and the last die statement. I guess when you say winblows you are referring to MS-Windows? But since when is the slash a path separator on Windows? This doesn't make any kind of sense. Sorry.

Comment: ya it didn't to me either until I printed out $ETLSpliter::configFile. it has //10.0.1.1/ it in due to local intranet ip. Thats what was messing it up.